# Getting User Activity Recognition once

Tags: android

After reading some article and documentation about UserActivityRecognition, i got many of tutorial told me to use new service, register, callback, etc, can i just having one function that return current user activity ([in constant](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity)) for my background service, thankyou